# In Yakuza 3 does the Tokyo Ishun magazine become unavailable?

Tags: yakuza-3

I'm in chapter 12 in Yakuza 3 and am trying to access the hidden menu options in restaurants and bars. However while I may have once seen the magazine necessary to unlock these items I seem to be unable to find the magazine at any of the M stores I've visited.

All I can find online is that I should be able to purchase it, but all I seem are two magazines that don't seem to help. I've checked the items in storage and there's nothing there that I can see.

Is the purchase of this time sensitive, or can I still find it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the M Stores should seemingly have a copy, I ended up finding a copy in the Poppo store in Chapter 12. Still nothing in the M store.

I picked up 5 (the total number I had room for), just in case, but thankfully these are not used up when you purchase a special menu item.

Looking further online I did find a thread that later on said you could find them in Poppo marts as well, but the first half-ish was solely talking about M stores having them. Since I rarely had to purchase healing items in my normal playthrough, I'm sure I stopped in there once when I first arrived and then never went back.

If I pick up Yakuza 1 and 2 and decide to replay the story in this one from start to finish I'll be sure to see if a copy ever shows up in the M stores.

Comment: Ordered a copy of 1 and picked up a copy of 2, so it's highly likely I'll play Yakuza 3 again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it in any M-store in Tokyo ... That's where I find mine

Comment: That's what I keep seeing online and in FAQs, but why do I just have Friday and the Young magazines? Everything I've read seems to suggest you can pick it up when you first get to Tokyo, so I fear I lost my chance.

Comment: Maybe but what I read seems to be there everytimes ... maybe a corrupt save file but that's odd :S Sorry if I can't help more.